# Dropping array rows that DUPLICATE defined column elements of other array rows

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Consider the np array sample below:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1,2,5,  4,2,7,  5,2,9],
                [4,4,1,  4,2,0,  3,6,4],
                [1,2,1,  4,2,2,  5,2,0],
                [1,2,7,  2,4,1,  5,2,8],
                [1,2,9,  4,2,8,  5,2,1],
                [4,2,0,  4,4,1,  5,2,4],
                [4,4,0,  4,2,6,  3,6,6],
                [1,2,1,  4,2,2,  5,2,0]])
```

PROBLEM: We are concerned only with **the first TWO columns of each element triplet**.  I want to remove array rows that duplicate these two elements of each triplet (in the same order).

In the example above, the rows with indices 0,2,4, and 7 are all of the form `[1,2,_,  4,2,_, 5,2,_]`.  So, we should keep `arr[0]`,and drop the other three.   Similarly, `row[6]` is dropped because it has the same pattern as row[1], namely `[4,4,_,  4,2,_, 3,6,_]`.
In the example given, the output should look like:

```
               [[1,2,5,  4,2,7,  5,2,9],
                [4,4,1   4,2,0,  3,6,4],
                [1,2,7,  2,4,1,  5,2,8],
                [4,2,0,  4,4,1   5,2,4]]
```

The part I'm struggling with most is that the solution should be general enough to handle arrays of 3, 6, 9, 12... columns. (always a multiple of 3, and we are always interested in duplications of the first **two columns of each triplet**.

Comment: What's the significance of the gap in columns?  Is this array (8,9) or (8,3,3) shape?

Comment: Rather than focus on what you want to remove, pay more attention to what you want to keep.  Even when you use a function like `np.delete` you are really constructing a new array with the selected rows or columns.  So identifying what you want to keep (conversely drop) and actually creating the new array are separate steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can create an array withonly the values you are interested in, you can pass that to [`np.unique()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) which has an option to `return_index`.

One way to get the groups you want is to delete every third column. Pass that to `np.unique()` and get the indices:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1,2,5,  4,2,7,  5,2,9],
                [4,4,1,   4,2,0,  3,6,4],
                [1,2,1,  4,2,2,  5,2,0],
                [1,2,7,  2,4,1,  5,2,8],
                [1,2,9,  4,2,8,  5,2,1],
                [4,2,0,  4,4,1,   5,2,4],
                [4,4,0,  4,2,6,  3,6,6],
                [1,2,1,  4,2,2,  5,2,0]])



unique_cols = np.delete(arr, slice(2, None, 3), axis=1)
vals, indices = np.unique(unique_cols, axis=0, return_index=True)

arr[sorted(indices)]
```

output:

```
array([[1, 2, 5, 4, 2, 7, 5, 2, 9],
       [4, 4, 1, 4, 2, 0, 3, 6, 4],
       [1, 2, 7, 2, 4, 1, 5, 2, 8],
       [4, 2, 0, 4, 4, 1, 5, 2, 4]])
```

Comment: Works very efficiently on large arrays.